# Masking controllers functions -- Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to hide or mask *example.com/users/$ID/edit* to be *example.com/profile/edit*.

config/routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

I've tried adding the route

```
match '/profile/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_profile
```

but, when I visit *example.com/profile/edit*, the edit method complains about not being able to find the user's ID.

Is there a way I can mask the ID from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to edit the current user's profile you could use the following in your edit action:

```
    def edit
      @user = User.find_by_id( params[:id] ) || current_user
    end
```

This will first try to look up the user by the id parameter returning nil if it can't find the user and if the return value is nil it will set `@user` to the return value of the `current_user` helper method. This assumes you're using something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which provides the `current_user` method to get the currently logged in user.

One other note. You should change match in your route to get to specify that only get requests are valid for the edit action.

```
    get 'profile/edit' => 'users#edit' , as: edit_profile
```

If you're trying to prevent users from editing other people's profiles you need something like the following after you load the user:

```
    redirect_to( root_path ) and return unless @user == current_user
```

This will keep the current user from editing another user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow logged in user to change it's profile, maybe you'll want to store user's id in the session.

So when user logs in you save it's ID into the session:

```
session[:user_id] = ...
```

Then your edit method will look like

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

If that solution is not what you want, than you maybe will just need to add the ':id' parameter to the match code.